# WordPress REST API without plugin using wp_query

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, wordpress, rest

I have developing an ionic application using WordPress as a backend. 
For this, I use wp_query to fetch the blog posts from WordPress and show it in ionic application.

Here the problem is, the post content is not parsing as a HTML in ionic. But in the WordPress editor and the front end of the blog web-site it rendered correctly. Please find below the screen shots and the code

**Rest API Code in WordPress**

```
$posts_array = array();

$args = array("post_type" => "post", "orderby" => "date", "order" => "DESC", "post_status" => "publish", "posts_per_page" => "-1");

$posts = new WP_Query($args);

if($posts->have_posts()):
    while($posts->have_posts()): 
        $posts->the_post();

        $post_array = array(
            'title'=>get_the_title(), 
            'permalink'=>get_the_permalink(), 
            'content'=>get_the_content(), 
            'date'=>get_the_date(), 
            'img'=>wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail')
        );
        array_push($posts_array, $post_array);

    endwhile;
    else:
        echo "{'posts' = []}";
        die();
endif;

echo json_encode($posts_array);
```

**HTML in ionic app**

```
<section class="list" ng-controller="postController">
    <a href="#" class="item" ng-repeat="post in postsList">
        <article>
            <img ng-src="{{post.img}}" class="item">
            <h2 class="noWhitespace">{{post.title}}</h2>
            <p class="noWhitespace">{{post.content}}</p> <!-- ng-bind-html="toTrustedHTML(post.content)"-->
        </article>
    </a>
</section>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller("postController",function ($scope, $http){ //, $sce
  $scope.postsList = [];

  $http({
    method: "GET",    
    url: "http://localhost/wordpress/blog-posts/",
  }).then(function(response){
    console.log(response)
    $scope.postsList = response.data;
  });

  /*$scope.toTrustedHTML = function (RESOURCE_URL) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(RESOURCE_URL);
  };*/

});
```

Even I tried ng-sanitize, and $sce  for HTML parsing in angular. 
Here `ng-bind-html="toTrustedHTML(html)"` is working, but again the problem is it does not have a line break between paragraphs. (showing a long text)

Thanks in advance.

**NOTE:**
we have Rest-WP API, and JSON-API plugins for WordPress to achieve this. 
but i need to achieve this **without plugin**.

[image]

**Updated on 25 Dec, 2016**

**How to pass the data to the another controller?**

In `'postController'` we got the response.data, which contains all the post details, if we click on the single post, how do we get the ID, title, content of that respective post. I tried with `$state.go()` but got undefined..

Thanks in advance

Comment: why do you not use the ng-bind-html you have in the comment there?

Comment: I tried with ng-bind-html..it is working.. but the content is not having line breaks between the paragraphs...

Comment: that is because wordpress has his own way of handling new lines in posts use wpautop() function to get the desired format

Answer (score 1):

adding the solution here for other users that might find this question:
Use ng-bind-html to have angular display the html and run the content form the database thru the wpautop() function to get the correct format

Comment: How to run the content form the database thru the wpautop() function without affecting the existing wordpress functionality? If possible can you please provide a code.

Comment: **How to pass the data to the another controller?** 

In `'postController'` we got the response.data, which contains all the post details, if we click on the single post, how do we get the ID, title, content of that respective post. I tried with `$state.go()` but got undefined..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It got it fixed by adding wpautop() function to the content in post array. The working code as shown below:

```
$post_array = array(
   'title'=>get_the_title(), 
   'permalink'=>get_the_permalink(), 
   'content'=>wpautop(get_the_content()), 
   'date'=>get_the_date(),
   'img'=>wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail')
);
```

and for controller

```
app.controller("postController",function ($scope, $http, $sce){
  $scope.postsList = [];

  $http({
    method: "GET",    
    url: "http://localhost/wordpress/blog-posts/",
  }).then(function(response){
    console.log(response)
    $scope.postsList = response.data;
  });

  $scope.toTrustedHTML = function (RESOURCE_URL) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(RESOURCE_URL);
  };

});
```

and also we use ng-bind-html in index.html

```
 <article>
     <img ng-src="{{post.img}}" class="item">
     <h2 class="noWhitespace">{{post.title}}</h2>
     <p class="noWhitespace" ng-bind-html="toTrustedHTML(post.content)"></p> 
</article>
```

Thanks to victor for guiding me in the right way.

Comment: How to pass the data to another controller? 

In 'postController' i got the response.data, which contains all the post details, if i click on the single post, how do i get the ID, title, content of that respective post.